# Как грамотно добавить проверку healthCheck() перед выполнением каждого ИТ?

Tags: java, spring, rest, тестирование

Есть Интеграционные тесты и приложение на спринг. 
Если приложению чего-то не хватило после загрузки - об этом можно узнать дернув на рест CheckHealth()
Но, как сделать, чтобы не добавлять во все ИТ вызов этого реста, а где-то в одном месте дернуть, и, если вернулся статус ок - выполнить тесты, иначе, пропустить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте  [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) метод аннотированный этой аннотацией будет запускаться перед запуском тестов.

В случае того что статут не *OK* генерируйте ошибку и тесты естественно не запустятся

Пример

```
@BeforeClass
public static void checkHealthStatus() {
    //тут пропишите логику
}
```

Comment: Тесты действительно скипаются, но в консоль, каждый из класса тестов бросает java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  HttpServerErrorException: 500

Comment: Проверку осуществляю методом Assume.assumeTrue(HttpStatus.OK.equals(res.getStatusCode()));

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov используйте `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue`